# temporary logging format in a same file

Tags: python, logging

i want all modules logs that import to the `main.py` save in `main.log` that i mention in `logging.basicConfig()` but with their formats

here is the code:

file `main.py`

```py
import module1
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="main.log", 
    format="%(asctime)s , <%(name)s> , %(levelname)s : %(message)s", 
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S",
    level=logging.DEBUG
)

def main(ip):
    lg = logging.getLogger("main")

    newformat="%(asctime)s , <%(name)s> ,  [" + ip + "] , %(levelname)s : %(message)s", 

    # do another things
    lg.debug("somthing done...")

    # call func1
    module1.func1()

    lg.debug("service done")


def main2(ip):
    lg = logging.getLogger("main")

    newformat="%(asctime)s , <%(name)s> ,  [" + ip + "] , %(levelname)s : %(message)s", 

    # do another things
    lg.debug("somthing done...")

    # call func1
    module1.func1()

    lg.debug("service done")


main("192.168.1.100")
main2("192.168.1.101")
```

file `module1.py`

```py
import logging

def func1():

    lg = logging.getLogger("module1.func1")
    lg.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # do somthing ...

    lg.debug("done")
```

the output is:
file `main.log`

```
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main1> , DEBUG : somthing done...
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <module1.func1> , DEBUG : done
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main1> , DEBUG : service done
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main2> , DEBUG : somthing done...
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <module1.func1> , DEBUG : done
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main2> , DEBUG : service done
```

but i want this with new format:

```py
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main1> , [192.168.1.100] , DEBUG : somthing done...
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <module1.func1> , DEBUG : done
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main1> , [192.168.1.100] , DEBUG : service done
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main2> , [192.168.1.101] , DEBUG : somthing done...
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <module1.func1> , DEBUG : done
2022-07-02 05:39:51 , <main2> , [192.168.1.101] , DEBUG : service done
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the best solution but this should get the job done

```
import module1
import logging

logging.basicConfig(
    filename="main.log",
    format="%(asctime)s , <%(name)s> , %(levelname)s : %(message)s",
    datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %I:%M:%S",
    level=logging.DEBUG
)


def setBasicConfigFormat(format):
    ROOT_LOGGER = logging.getLogger()
    ROOT_LOGGER.handlers[0].setFormatter(logging.Formatter(
        format
    ))


def main(ip):
    lg = logging.getLogger("main")

    newformat = "%(asctime)s , <%(name)s> ,  [" + \
        ip + "] , %(levelname)s : %(message)s"
    setBasicConfigFormat(newformat)

    # do another things
    lg.debug("somthing done...")

    # call func1
    module1.func1()

    lg.debug("service done")


def main2(ip):
    lg = logging.getLogger("main")

    newformat = "%(asctime)s , <%(name)s> ,  [" + \
        ip + "] , %(levelname)s : %(message)s"
    setBasicConfigFormat(newformat)
    # do another things
    lg.debug("somthing done...")

    # call func1
    module1.func1()

    lg.debug("service done")


main("192.168.1.100")
main2("192.168.1.101")
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way with `logging.LoggerAdapter(logger, {parameters})`

you can pass vars to log format

so I wrote a function to return logger and format and handlers want.

```py
def get_logger(name:str, path:str, ip:bool = False, format: bool or str = False) -> logging.Logger:
    
    fmt = format if format else f"%(asctime)s , <%(name)s> , {' [%(ip)s] ,' if ip else ''} , %(levelname)s : %(message)s"

    logConf = logging.getLogger(name)
    # set level of logger
    logConf.setLevel(get_log_level())
    # stream handler for Errors 
    stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    # set level of this stream handler
    stream_handler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
    stream_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    logConf.addHandler(stream_handler)
    # file handler
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler(path)
    # set level of this file handler
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    file_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    logConf.addHandler(file_handler)

    return logConf
```

and call this function in each module body and pass IP with `logging.Logger.Adapter()`

`module1.py`

```py
ip = get_ip_from_some_where()

lgConfig = get_logger(__name__, "module1.log", ip=True)
lg = logging.LoggerAdapter(lgConfig, {"ip": ip})
lg.setLevel(logging.debug) # make sure to set level

lg.info('started')
# some codes
lg.info('done')
```

or you can use it in functions and logging chain
`module2.py`

```py
ip = get_ip_from_some_where()

lgConfig = get_logger(__name__, "module1.log", ip=True)

def func1():
    lg = logging.getLogger("__name__.func1") # define func1 as a chain of __name__
    lg = logging.LoggerAdapter(lg, {"ip": ip})
    lg.setLevel(logging.debug) # make sure to set level

    # do something

    lg.info('started')
    # some codes
    lg.info('done')

func1()
```